# How to create a custom VF page with dynamically generated HTML code and what VF component to use?

Tags: visualforce, rerender, pageblocktable, label

I have a dynamically generated HTML code in apex.

I need to put and render this HTML in a custom VF page.

How that can be achieved?

If I need an `<apex:outputLabel>` please advise how to put the dynamically generated HTML code in the `<apex:outputLabel>`?

Or do I need some other VF component such as `<apex:pageBlockTable>`?
Please advise.

My dynamically generated HTML code is generating a table such as:
[image]

Which VF component is the most appropriate to generate such table?

That is my VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="LeadDuplicateController" tabStyle="Lead"> 
  <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Lead Information">
            <apex:outputText value="{!plainHTML}" escape="false" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

AND That is the controller class to the VF page:

```
public with sharing class LeadDuplicateController {

    Lead objLead;

    public String plainHTML { get; set; }

    public LeadDuplicateController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        objLead = (Lead)controller.getRecord();
    }
}
```

My HTML code is in another class and another method.

How from that other method I can invoke the setter method in the LeadDuplicateController so that value of the HTML to be visualized and displayed in the VF page?

Comment: What is your reason for generating HTML, presumably by building a giant string, in Apex? Why not just provide the data to the VF page and let the VF page generate the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `apex:outputText` to drop plain HTML in to the page:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!plainHTML}" escape="false" />
```

Please note that you should sanitize the output to avoid script injection attacks if such a possibility exists by using `String.escapeHtml4` on any user strings that you merge into the HTML.

Comment: thank you so much for your advise sfdcfox. By `plain HTML` do you have in mind pure and static HTML? If the `{!plainHTML}` is a variable how to put my HTML code generated in apex into `plainHTML`?

Comment: @lemdev no, `plainHTML` is a variable, such as `public String plainHTML { get; set; }`, and you would set it by whatever means necessary.

Comment: I've included the code of my VF page as well as of my controller class. I need to know how from that other method I can invoke the setter method in the LeadDuplicateController so that value of the HTML can be visualized and displayed in the VF page?

Comment: My HTML code is in another class and another method. I need to know how from that other method I can invoke the setter method in the LeadDuplicateController so that value of the HTML to be visualized and displayed in the VF page?

Comment: @lemdev You would just call the method from your constructor or an action method.  Exactly what you'd do depends on if the method is static or not, etc.